# How can I remove noise in asterisk PBX?

Tags: asterisk

How can I remove noise in asterisk PBX? Now I am using Digium pri card it generates noise while calling.

Can anyone please help on this issue?

Comment: what sort of 'noise' ? do you have a clock/sync source setup?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Denoise()`

```
[from-trunk]
exten => 3000,1,Answer()                      
exten => 3000,2,Playback(welcome)             
exten => 3000,3,Set(DENOISE(rx)=on)           
exten => 3000,4,Set(DENOISE(tx)=on)           
exten => 3000,5,Dial(SIP/300@10.9.24.50:5060) 
exten = _X.,n,Hangup()
```

answering on ext 3000

Playing a IVR here (Optional)

Noise reduction on receive

Noise reduction on Transmit

Sending call to other PBX extn

End of the dialplanenter code here

Answer (score 0):

PRI card is digital one, it not able get noise, it not do any analog operations.

So noise is somewhere on PSTN/PRI side, not on your pbx.

You can use function DENOISE, but it can decrease sound level.

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show function DENOISE 

  -= Info about function 'DENOISE' =- 

[Synopsis]
Apply noise reduction to audio on a channel. 

[Description]
The DENOISE function will apply noise reduction to audio on the channel that
it is executed on. It is very useful for noisy analog lines, especially when
adjusting gains or using AGC. Use 'rx' for audio received from the channel
and 'tx' to apply the filter to the audio being sent to the channel.
Examples:
exten => 1,1,Set(DENOISE(rx)=on)
exten => 1,2,Set(DENOISE(tx)=off)

[Syntax]
DENOISE(channeldirection)

[Arguments]
channeldirection
    This can be either 'rx' or 'tx'  the values that can be set to this
    are either 'on' and 'off'

[See Also]
Not available
```

Comment: It depends on the sort of noise - I had sync issues with PRI cards before where clocking was an issue and it put noise across all the channels. It in the end it was down to a dodgy circuit provided by the telco. Once we changed where the clock source was set the issue went away

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal that PRI is giving noise. You need to do the below.

Originate the call from the PRI between two external phones to make sure PRI is not having the noise. If you are observing the noise that must be PRI fault or Card fault.